# scanf() behaviour for strings with more than one word

Tags: c, string, function, scanf

Well I've been programming in **C** for quite a while now, and there is this question about the function `scanf()`

**here is my problem:**

> I know that every element in ASCII table is a character and I even know that %s is a data specified for a string which is a collection of characters

**My questions:**

1.why does `scanf()` stops scanning after we press enter. If enter is also character why cant it be added as a component of the string that is being scanned.

2.My second question and what I require the most is why does it stops scanning after a space, when space is again a character?

> **Note:** My question is not about how to avoid these but how does this happen

I'd be happy if this is already addressed, I'd gladly delete my question and even if I've presumed something wrong please let me know

Comment: Because that is how `scanf` works? From the `man` page: _Matches a sequence of bytes that are not white-space characters._

Comment: It's only helpful if you don't want to read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my reading of your question, both of your numbered questions are the same:

> Why does `scanf` with a format specifier of `%s` stop reading after encountering a space or newline.

And the answer to both of your questions is: Because that is what `scanf` with the `%s` format specifier is documented to do.

From [the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html):

> `%s` Matches a sequence of bytes that are not white-space characters.

A space and a newline character (generated by the enter key) are white-space characters.

Comment: Thank you @SeanBright... I didn't know that scanf(),right after it encounters a white space

Comment: `scanf("%s", ...)` does not stop just after encountering a space or newline.  It reads and consumes spaces and newlines until it reaches non-white-space.  After saving some non-white-space, _then_ it will  stop after encountering a space or newline.

Comment: Right. That was explained in exhaustive detail in the other answer to this question.

Comment: @chux I think there was a misunderstanding there, OP means "why does scanf, after reading some non-whitespace, stop when it encounters a space or newline"

Answer (score 3):

"why does scanf() stops scanning after we press enter." is not always true.

The `"%s"` directs `scanf()` as follows

```
char buffer[100];
scanf("%s", buffer);
```

1. Scan and consume all white-space including `'\n'` generated from *multiple* <kbd>Enter</kbd>s. This data is not saved.

> Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier  C11dr §7.21.6.2 8

2. Scan and save all non-white-space characters.  Continue doing so until a white-space is encountered.

> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters  §7.21.6.2 12

3. This white-space is put back into `stdin` for the next input function.  (OP's 2nd question)
4. A null character is appended to `buffer`.
5. Operations may stop short if EOF occurs.
6. If too much data is save in `buffer`, it is UB.
7. If some non-white-space data is saved, return 1.  If EOF encountered, return EOF.

Note: `stdin` is usually line buffered, so no keyboard data is given to `stdin` until a `'\n'` occurs.

Answer (score -1):

I made miniprogram with scanf for get multiple name without stop on space or ever enter.
i use while

```
Scanf("%s",text);

While (1)
{
Scanf("%s",text1)
If (text1=='.'){break;}
//here i simple add text1 to text
}
```

This way i get one line if use the .
Now i use
scanf("%[^\n]",text);
It work great.